# How to Get the count of sharepoint list items based on months

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a list named as Tickets.and have the fields title,status,date,submitted by. the status field have the choice as open,closed,pending,drafts. From this list I have to get the Count as monthly results.I mean i want to count the list if status is open,and how many tickets are open for every month..Like this i have to get the count for all(closed ,pending,drafts).how can i achieve this one please help me

Answer (score 0):

Sample demo:

[image]

```
http://sp:12001/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tickets/$count?$filter=(Date ge datetime'2019-11-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (Date le datetime'2019-12-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (StatusValue eq 'Open')
```

[image]

Or, SharePoint rest api to get json data(item details).

```
http://sp:12001/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tickets')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=(Date ge datetime'2019-11-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (Date le datetime'2019-12-01T00%3a00%3a00') and (Status eq 'Open')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..But I need full function can you please?

Comment: And one more thing is I want to get the count for all 12 months.how can i did this?